# Send 201 response as soon as you receive the message, before saving it to DB - Python 3.6

Tags: python, post, request

We have a python (3.6) script that receive data from a device.

We need to send 201 response as soon as we receive the message, before saving it to DB.

How to do a return 201 and keep the script running?

```
    def main(args):
        '''
        Main function - runs every time the function is executed.
        '''
        print("HELLO")
        ## need to send a return 201 right now and continue running the 
        ## code to save data into DB
        ...
        args = {"temp1":{"timestamp": posix_dt, "value": store_details['value']}}
        req = update_device(device, args, token)
        return {"status": "Ok", "result": req.json()}
        ## saved to DB
```

Many thanks for your help.
Best,

Comment: That code is nothing, it's just an empty function. Could you share a block of code of your real server ?

Comment: we need to know what framework you are using. and the actual function which is needed to be modified.

Comment: @azro Many thanks, I just added some block of code

Comment: @xcodz-dot Thanks a lot, I don't use framework, just Python 3.6 script

Comment: as it looks like, when you send back the response you include req.json() data with it. but req is calculated when the function update_device is called. so you can not send back the response in that way. If you remove result parameter in return value, i can help. because if you do not then the program is supposed to wait until code to save to db is complete

Comment: I just need to send a 201 response at the beginning (without data) and then save the data in the data (with another return). Many thanks!